# What is wrong with my express parse setup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Server

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("listening at 4000"));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json({limit: "1mb"})); 


//POST method route
app.post("/clientApi", (req, res) => {
  // res.send("POST request to the homepage")
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Client

```
function checkData() {
    let summoner = playerName.value;

    let fetchData = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(summoner),
    }

    fetch("/clientApi", fetchData)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log("Success: ", data);
    });   
}
```

Everything worked fine until I tried calling for Express.json but I don't see any syntax error.
The client side could send data to the server.
But it was too much data so I used "req.body" to try and get exactly what I wanted, but on the terminal its undefined. So that's when I decided to try using express.json which is where the error came up.

**Error Message**

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending an object rather than just a string stringified such as

```html
<script>
    const playerName = {
        value: "foobar"
    };

    function checkData() {
        const summoner = { ...playerName };

        const fetchData = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(summoner),
        }

        fetch("/clientApi", fetchData)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log("Success: ", data);
            });
    }

    checkData();
</script>
```

Express won't be able to decode it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the {} after `app.listen(4000, () => {console.log("listening at 4000")});` that should fix it

Comment: listen should't be last

Comment: Unfortunately neither is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you forgot to make proper JSON formate at client site:

```
function checkData() {
let summoner = playerName.value;
let sendData = {};
sendData.summoner = summoner;

let fetchData = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(sendData),
}

fetch("/clientApi", fetchData)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log("Success: ", data);
});
```

}

**NOTE:** Data you pass inside JSON.stringify() should a proper JSON Object. So that it can parse on the other side.

Comment: Yes that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `fetch("/clientApi", fetchData)` include `http://localhost:4000/clientApi`?

Comment: Maybe I could put it idk, but that's not the issue. Like I said in the explanation the fetch() on the client-side sends the data just fine. Its the server code express.json I need to figure out what went wrong so that it can parse the data.

Comment: If you are trying to call it from the client, have you added CORS?